# UIButton titleLabel text bottom to its frame

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How can i display the UIButton titleLabel text to bottom of its frame. Currently i am using the UIEdge top margin and setting the negative UIButton image width, result is not as expected. i also want to place the image center to its frame.
`

```
let leftButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.layer.borderWidth = 2
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.ublGray1().cgColor
            button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: leftButtonImage)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
            button.tintColor = UIColor.cerulean()
            button.layer.masksToBounds = false
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 37
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.setTitle(leftButtonTitle, for: .normal)
            button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 110, left: -26, bottom: 0, right: 0)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.charcoalGrey(), for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.aspiraMedium(size: 16)
            return button
        }()
```

`
[image: Code Result]

Comment: I would like to use a `UIView` containing an `imageView`, `label` and `button`. It will be easy and appropriate in terms of aulayouts, contentMode, multiple lines text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its not separate lable see I have show you a arrow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when you assign image to uibutton the results will be different

Answer (score 0):

How about setting "Title Insets" - bottom - to a negative number? It works.

But if you want it to stick to the bottom of the frame, it won't work, so... how about this:

```
bt.titleEdgeInsets.top = (bt.imageView?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)!
```

or `bt.titleEdgeInsets.top = (bt.imageView?.alignmentRectInsets.bottom)!`